# How to hide the output of a command ran inside sytem()?

Tags: perl

I have looked all over and found plenty of answers, and after much trial and error, I have come to this conclusion: I don't know.

I am running a thing in Perl:

```
my $command = sprintf('commandHereDoingSCPishThingsThatHasToRunInMyShell', options, options, options);
system($command);
```

When I run my script in my terminal window, I see the output of the command inside the sprintf() function.

I would like for the output to be re-directed to a file, and to not have to see the program executing on my terminal window.

Thanks!

Comment: Anything wrong with `command > file`?

Comment: _I see the output of the command inside the sprintf() function._  Impossible.

Comment: the sprintf function seems not to like it.... and for some reason, it STILL prints.

Comment: @7stud it is very much so possible, I can definitively say that, because I can see it happening.

Comment: Try it.  Here is an entire perl program: `my $cmd = sprintf('ls -%s%s', 'a', 'l');`  You claim that will show the listing of the current directory in your terminal.  It won't.  No way.  No how.  Impossible.

Comment: While that is an entire, it's ignoring the aforementioned system() call, which I believe is where this whole debacle is coming from. @7stud

Comment: Hah.  Yet you said this:  
_I see the output of the command inside the sprintf() function._  So what you appear to mean is:  _I see the output of the command inside `system()`_.

Comment: because I do.... @7stud

Comment: Well, I just showed you how that was impossible.  The output you are seeing is not coming from anything to do with the `sprintf()` line.

Comment: There is a command, that is being run, by the system call. The command's elements are being defined by the sprintf function, and then system is used to execute the command in the terminal. I am seeing the output, from the command that is defined inside the sprintf function, when it is executed by the system call. @7stud

Comment: @Oly396 what *do* you want to happen to the output?

Comment: I'd ideally like to have the output of the command's output placed in a file. @ysth

Comment: _The command's elements are being defined by the sprintf function_ -- How is that relevant?

Comment: @7stud before you go quoting things, make sure you quote the _whole_ thing: "When I run my script in my terminal window, I see the output of the command inside the sprintf() function. " I said I saw the output of the command _inside_ the sprintf function. I was mearly explaining _which_ output I did not want to see.

Comment: You said " The output you are seeing is not coming from anything to do with the sprintf() line." Which is absolutely **not** true. That's why it's there. I was answering your question, that's how it's relevant. @7stud

Comment: What I'm getting at is how would your question differ if you had asked, "How can I stop a system() call from outputting to my terminal?"

Comment: @7stud It wouldn't. So what **I'm** getting at, is that you are really not answering anything, and instead of being helpful, you're just arguing semantics.

Comment: Btw, you should be using `shell_quote` from String::ShellQuote, not `sprintf`.

Comment: Crikey, get a room, you guys.

Comment: @Oly396: The confusion comes from your use of *inside*, which is unfamiliar. You're implying that that's where you see the output, and it would be better to write "the command created by the `sprintf` function" or perhaps "from the `sprintf` function". That said, it seems to me that **7stud** was being unnecessarily quarrelsome, continuing to argue after your meaning became clear.

Answer (score 2):

Raw use of perl's system() is discouraged because it isn't trivial to detect errors and come up with a relevant error message.  Consider using [`IPC::System::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple).  Since you want to capture the output, use its capture().

```
use IPC::System::Simple 'capture';

my $output = capture($command);  # dies if command fails; catch this with eval if necessary
File::Slurp::write_file('somefile', $output);
```

Alternatively, just redirect the output to a file in your command:

```
use IPC::System::Simple 'system';
system("$command >somefile");
```

Comment: That is awesome! I have a small issue though, I don't have access to IPC::System::Simple, as this is a remote machine and I'm not admin on said box. :/

Comment: `my $cmd_stdout_output = \`$cmd\``